# using a do-while loop to validate user input and then allow valid input to be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this assignment to make this allow the user to put a valid input and display the result using a do while loop. Right now it works to allow the user input but wont display the result from the counter var. any help would be great thanks

```js
alert("Sum the Numbers Application");

var sum = 0;
var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter the top numbers to sum", "5"));
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  sum += i;
}
if (num <= 0 || num > 100 || isNaN(num)) {
  alert("Not a valid entry.");
} else {
  alert("Sum of the numbers from 1 through " + num + " is " + sum + ".")
}

do {
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter the top numbers to sum", "5"));
}
while (num <= 0 || num > 100 || isNaN(num))
```

Comment: _"it works to allow the user input but wont display the result from the counter var"_ Not certain what you mean? What is expected result?

Comment: You're calculating the sum before you do the `do-while` loop. Isn't that obviously backwards?

Comment: Sorry I just started with js. So the pop up windows work to tell the user that the entry is invalid. Then it prompts the user to enter a number again like in the beginning. however if there is a valid entry nothing happens. the task is to be able to run the loop until the entry is valid and then display the sum of the numbers

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what is desired.  The while loop needs to be at the top checking for a valid response.  Once a valid response is entered the loop can exit and the sum is calculated.

```js
alert("Sum the Numbers Application");

var sum = 0;
var valid = false;
do {
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter the top numbers to sum", "5"));
  if (num <= 0 || num > 100 || isNaN(num)) {
    alert("Not a valid entry.");
  } else {
    valid = true;
  }
}
while (!valid)

for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  sum += i;
}
alert("Sum of the numbers from 1 through " + num + " is " + sum + ".")
```